# Reading line by line from a specific row in a tab file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read from a tab file from a specific row and  I want to process the information line by line in order to create a list with those lines. I read the documentation, but I couldn`t find something useful.

To be more clear I will give an example:
Given the file:

id  conversation

1. Hello, How are you
2. I am fine, thanks for asking
3. I am glad to hear that

I want to read just conversation row and create the list like this:

```
list=['Hello,How are you', 'I am fine, thanks for asking', 'I am glad to hear that']
```

Comment: add your code please

Comment: Have you looked into this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Answer (score 0):

Here is a an example with a oneliner:

```
import io

file="""id conversation

1 Hello, How are you

2 I am fine, thanks for asking

3 I am glad to hear that"""

[' '.join(row.strip('\n').split(" ")[1:]) for row in io.StringIO(file).readlines() if row.strip('\n')][1:]
```

Prints

```
['Hello, How are you',
 'I am fine, thanks for asking',
 'I am glad to hear that']
```

---

```
import io

file="""id conversation

1 Hello, How are you

2 I am fine, thanks for asking

3 I am glad to hear that"""

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(file)

with open("test.txt") as f:
    mylist = [' '.join(row.strip('\n').split(" ")[1:]) for row in f.readlines() if row.strip('\n')][1:]

mylist
```